# GridOptions interface ag-Grid

Tags: typescript, ag-grid

On ag-Grid [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/), there is mentioned a lot about this **GridOptions interface**.

[Grid Properties](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-properties/), [Grid Events](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/), [Grid Callbacks](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-callbacks/), all 'claim' that

```
this options are available through the GridOptions interface
```

I managed to access, for example, the *columnDefs* property without any 'usage' of this *gridOptions*, by the following:

### .html

```
<ag-grid-angular 
            style="margin: auto;
            width: 80%; height: 70%;
            #agGrid
            class="ag-theme-material"
            [rowData]="rowData" 
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
            >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

## .ts

```
private columnDefs;

constructor() {
    this.columnDefs = ...; // columns array
   }
```

However, I came to a point where i don't know how to integrate certain features without calling this gridOptions, like [accessing row nodes](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#accessing-row-nodes) provided by the api.

**How can i mention / reach to this gridOptions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to Mention gridOptions in your HTML put the below code

```
 [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
```

and in your Component.ts

```
public gridOptions: GridOptions;
```

on ngonINIT

```
this.gridOptions.columnDefs=this.columnDefs;
```

Then you can access this gridoptions anywhere in the code.

Comment: That doesn't really work, during onInit the gridOption is still not there. Actually not even in ongrid ready... which worries me